# What is the effect of Gaussian noise on image histogram?

Tags: image-processing, gaussian, noise

What is the effect of Gaussian noise on an image histogram does it increase or decrease certain values?

Comment: install ImageJ, take a couple of images and add gaussian noise, then compare histograms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider a single-pixel image with Gaussian noise applied. Its's histogram is single bar of height 1. Application of gaussian noise will move its bar to the left or to the right. If we'll perform many experiments with given image and given distribution parameters we'll that in average bar moves on the distance which equals to mean of distribution.

The effect of application of noise to larger image must be similar - if histogram has any anomalies, they will move towards left or right for m points, where m is distribution mean, and effect of any anomaly will be slightly less sharp than on the original image.